# GNU coreutils and GNU Bash

Tags: bash, osx, gnu

I confused with GNU coreutils and GNU Bash,

I have installed [Bash GNU Project - Free Software Foundation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/),
Should I install [Coreutils - GNU core utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)

How could I distinguish them?

Comment: Bash is a shell, coreutils is a bunch of commands you run from a shell. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU coreutils provides implementations of the core utilities found on any Unix system, such as `ls`, `cp`, `nice`, `tr` etc.

Bash is a shell.  An interactive shell will give you a command prompt from which you can type in commands.  Bash (like all Unix shells) can also execute shell scripts.

Bash and GNU coreutils are maintained as two separate projects<sup>1</sup>.

If you are using macOS, then you are likely already running the `bash` shell (albeit a quite old release of it).  With [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), you may install a newer version (`brew install bash`).

Homebrew also provides GNU coreutils (`brew install coreutils`). Installing GNU coreutils through Homebrew on macOS will give you access to all GNU core utilities with a `g` prefix, such as `gls`, `gmkdir` etc. (or you may read the installation message and enable them without this prefix).

---

<sup>1</sup> Other common utilities, such as GNU `awk` (`gawk` on non-Linux systems), GNU `sed` (`gsed` on non-Linux systems), and GNU `find` (often `gfind` on non-Linux systems) are also maintained as separate projects and are therefore available as separate packages.  With Homebrew on macOS, you would install the three packages `gawk`, `gnu-sed`, and `findutils` to get access to these three particular GNU commands.

Comment: so coreutils are not a bash?

Comment: @avirate `bash` is not part of coreutils, no.